# Run a macro when certain cells change in Excel but from my Personal workbook

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem**: I have found many postings (including Microsoft's own support site) containing information on how to run a macro when certain cells change in Excel. I can get it to work, but I need to store that sub in my Personal.xlsb workbook and have it affect named worksheets in another workbook.

**Background**: I receive an Excel file from a third party often and run a series of routines on it, with all Macros stored in my Personal.xlsb hidden workbook. Part of the process requires me to "undo" many of the formatting changes I have made automatically when a user enters a date in a specific cell. I would like to call those "undo" subs on 5 separate worksheets as soon as a user does make a date entry in cells specified on any of the given 5 worksheets. However, all of the help on this that I have already read online has me add the code to the exact worksheet to which the changes need to occur. I want to store that code in a module in my Personal workbook so that it will run on any Workbook containing the worksheet names...similar to the way I have my other queries laid out.

**Code so far**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("W9")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Question**: How do I revise the sub in order to put it into effect in all of my workbooks containing the specified worksheets? Or is there a better option for me somewhere out there?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could respond to the actions of a different user using code stored in your personal macro workbook? That's the impression I got from your question, so perhaps I misunderstood what you're looking for...

Comment: To clarify, I understand that I would need to add the code to each user's personal workbook so that they would have the same functionality as I would.

Comment: OK - if you want to do that then you'd need to capture events at the application level. See here for an overview: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim. I read through that article, and the other referenced article on that page, but I think this is still beyond me...I just can't get the event to work when it's located in a separate workbook. Oh well... Can you recommend a good book for VB/VBA beginners?

Answer (score 0):

Since I faced the **same problem**, I worked my way through Chip Pearson's instructions and will provide you with a more comprehensive guide.

I can also really encourage you to read your way through [Chip Pearson's great summary](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) on events. I know it's a lot to digest, but it will greatly help you understand what we actually do here.

As an overview, these are the steps we are going to perform:

1. Add a class module for our event handlers (This is where the actual event handling code will go)
2. Add an event handler to our *personal.xlsb*'s `ThisWorkbook` module to wire-up our event handler class
3. Enjoy infinite event handling loops because we changed the `Target.Value` :-P (*optional*)

Let's get started.

#### 1. Add a class module

First, we need to create a cozy plaze to put all our event handlers. We will use a class module for this, since it provides some nice structure and you immediately know where to look for your application level event handlers.

In your `personal.xlsb`'s VBA project create a new class by *right clicking* in the project browser -> *insert* -> *class module*.

Rename the class to *CAppEventHandler* by changing the name in the properties pane.

Add the source code listed below (both the setup part and the event handling part) to the class you just created. (*Make sure to read the comments, because they add some additional information to what we are doing and why.*)

#### 2. Add the initializing event handler

Now we need to make sure our event handlers are "activated" when our `personal.xlsb` is opened (so anytime you open Excel :)).

To do this, double click your `ThisWorkbook` module and add the code below.

Now you are actually already good to go and can test your event handling. The only thing you will have to do beforehand (in order to trigger the "wiring-up" process) is **restart Excel**.

#### *Notes*

- I added a check for the current sheet's name at the beginning of the event handler - so make sure your sheet is named "MySheet" :)
- You can set a breakpoint inside the handler and watch it in action just like any other piece of VBA code

> **And a word of warning** (aka *3. Enjoy infinite event handling loops*)
>   When I tested this, I naively used `Target.Value = "It wooooorks!"` as the code to be executed if we changed the right cell on the right sheet. **That was not good.**
>   See the last snippet of code (also taken from [Chip's post](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)) for how to prevent such an event loop.

## Source code

#### In the `CAppEventHandler` class (setup)

```vb
Option Explicit

' Declare our own reference to the Application object
' WithEvents is needed to capture the events of the application object
' (Note: The events 'bubble up' from the Worksheet to the Workbook and
'        finally to the Application.
'        So event handlers in the Sheet module are executed first
'        (if any handlers are declared), then the ones in the Workbook
'        module (again, if they are declared) and finally the ones
'        in the Application module.)
Private WithEvents App As Application

' Whenever a new object of a class is instantiated, the _Initialize-Sub is called,
' that's why we use this Sub to get the reference to the current Application object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

#### In the `CAppEventHandler` class (actual event handling)

```vb
' Here is the actual code executed whenever the event reaches the Application level
' (see above for the order of 'bubbling up' of the events) and hasn't been marked
' as handled before
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sh.Name <> "MySheet" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim rngKeyCells As Range
    Set rngKeyCells = Sh.Range("A5")

    If Intersect(rngKeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Do our actual work
    MsgBox "It wooooorks!", vbInformation

    ' Note: If you want to change the contents of your keyCells, you will
    '       have to make sure to prevent an infinite event loop (i.e. using
    '       Application.EnableEvents = False because otherwise changing
    '       the value in your macro will trigger the event again

End Sub
```

#### In the `ThisWorkbook` module

```vb
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' The following code must be placed in the "ThisWorkbook" module of your personal.xlsb
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Option Explicit

Private OurEventHandler As CAppEventHandler

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Since we declared so in our _Initialize-Sub this wire-up the current
    ' Application object in our EventHandler class
    Set OurEventHandler = New CAppEventHandler
End Sub
```

#### How to prevent event loops

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

(from [Chip Pearson's comprehensive post on events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx))