# Re-using a VBA macro with "Worksheet_Change" event in all open workbooks in a single file

Tags: vba, excel

The following VBA code snippet should be executed in all open workbooks within a single Excel file (*.xlsm):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
...
End Sub
```

We do not want to copy the code in each workbook to reduce code duplication.

When trying to create a new Macro via the Excel "Macro" dialog it offers the possibility to locate the Macro in:

1. all open workbooks
2. this/current workbook
3. current file

When choosing (1) in combination with a Macro name, e.g. "MultiSelect" Excel jumps in the VBA editor and scaffolds a basic method according to the given name:

```
Sub MultiSelect()
...
End Sub
```

Our question: how to guarantee reacting on "Worksheet_Change" events within this macro?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: Following [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) shows section "Event Code Location" where it is mentioned that "_For sheet (both worksheet and chart sheet) level events, the event procedure code must be placed in the Sheet module associated with that sheet_". Finally, does it mean there is no possibility to prevent code duplication in that case?

Comment: You can write the event handler in a separate workbook to handle an application level event and then turn that into an add-in. That is a popular choice for people in your situation.

Comment: Got it :) It's working :) Thanx for your help! Especially, reading [Application Events In A New Class Module](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx) helped.

Comment: Single problem: "App_SheetChange" event procedure is called twice. Can we prevent that?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie: do you know why the event procedure is executed twice?

Comment: Are you seeing that happen when you just click on a tab or are you changing the sheet programatically e.g. `Sheets("AnotherSheet").Select` ?

Comment: Well, in sub "**App_SheetChange()**" I'm changing a cell's value using:
`Target.Value = newVal`
within a sheet.

Comment: Yes sorry - Worksheet_Change - perhaps there is a cell on another sheet that is linked to the cell you are changing and therefore another event fires.... sorry hard to say !

Comment: I enriched the code with:
`Application.EnableEvents` statements. The problem only occurs after having changed the worksheet manually and executing the VBA code there.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of "[Robin Mackenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765395/robin-mackenzie)" I found a solution :) Especially, reading section [Application Events In A New Class Module](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx) helped. So, I created a new class named "**CExcelEvents**":

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'gets the code more robust when the SheetChange event is called twice
    If Me.EnableEvents = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ...//code to centralize
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Me.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'setting a variable for this object
    Me.EnableEvents = True
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

and added in each worksheet - where the central code located in **CExcelEvents** has to be executed - the following object creation scaffold:

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

To prevent eventloops, see: [Run a macro when certain cells change in Excel but from my Personal workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067908/run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel-but-from-my-personal-workbook)